# Cannot select range for sheet names with special characters (OLE DB SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, excel, oledb

I'm trying to select data from Excel using OLE DB, but the other sheet names in the provided file has special characters.

For example: Sample_Sheet - #1

How do I go about this?

I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Sample_Sheet - #1$]
```

and it displays the data.

However, when I specify a range in the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Sample_Sheet - #1$D7:G22]
```

OLE DB throws an error

> Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object

Any insights will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you *can* use row based selection so you have to filter it in the where condition like regular sql

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` statement looks very dubious.

Here is how it is usually done in SSMS:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'Excel 12.0 Xml;
    Database=e:\Temp\SheetWithTable.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [SheetWithTable$A1:B3]');
```